# Puzzle: Alternate SQL Syntax

Tags: sql

I've been working this puzzle and I am stuck on this very last bit. I have a single SQL statement in a SQL query:

```
UPDATE courses SET pid=? WHERE course_name=?;
```

Parameters are passed and replace the ?s sequentially like so: (query, "Biology", 345533).

How can I change my SQL syntax (ie switch the order of pid=? and course_name=?) to point "Biology" to course_name and 345533 to pid?

Rules: Only one (1) SQL statement is allowed. Cannot change the order of parameters.

Comment: Does `UPDATE courses SET pid=?2 WHERE course_name=?1` count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that Cade Roux is on the right track in terms of what is desired, you could try:

```
Update c
Set pid =   Case
                When course_name = ? Then ?
                Else pid
                End
```

Comment: FWIW, I would be very worried about the execution plan for this because it may do an entire table scan.

Comment: @Cade Roux - *May* do a table scan? If it could do something other than a table scan, that would be a neat trick.

Comment: I don't put anything past an optimizer these days, but I would consider it a neat trick.

Comment: Elegant.  I was thinking about WITH AS

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if c is an updatable set by ANSI rules, but I'll try this in a real platform in a minute...

```
WITH c AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM courses
    WHERE course_name = ?
)
UPDATE c
SET pid = ?
```

This appears to work fine in T-SQL (SQL Server 2005 and up support common table expressions) and there is a runnable example at https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/100124/

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE C SET C.pid=D.pid
  FROM COURSES C
  JOIN (SELECT ? AS course_name, ? AS pid) D ON D.course_name = C.course_name
```

This works in SQL Server (2008), but is not ANSI compliant as far as I know.